# Select all checkbox functionality in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, checkbox, selectall

I have a select all checkbox followed by individual checkboxes corresponding to each record which comes from database.
How do I implement a javascript function such that when a person checks Select all,all the checkboxes get selected and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

first give an id to your select all check box say "selectall" and give a class to all other check boxes as allcheck and try using this code .

```
  $("#selectall").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.allcheck').each(function(){
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
    }
    else
    {

        $('.allcheck').each(function(){
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
    }


});
```

When user unchecks the box all should be unchecked  , I guess that is also an expected functionality

NOTE : - I have given this answer assuming that you are using jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function checkAll(id) {
    var checkboxCollection = document.getElementById('<%= chkint.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxCollection.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxCollection[i].type.toString().toLowerCase() == "checkbox") {
            checkboxCollection[i].checked = id.checked;
        }
    }
}

function select() {
    var count = 0;
    var chkSelectAll = document.getElementById('<%= selectall.ClientID %>');
    var chkList = document.getElementById('<%= chkint.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < chkList.length; i++) {
        if (chkList[i].checked == true) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == chkList.length)
        chkSelectAll.checked = true;
    else 
        chkSelectAll.checked = false;        
}
```

In this code, `chkint` is the ID of Checkboxlist and `selectall` is the ID of selectall checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Aravind, using jQuery you could group all your checkboxes in a container and give it an ID and give your SelectAll checkbox an ID.  After that code is simple, see alse [here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDDCC/):

```
$("#selectall").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $("#selectallcontainer :checkbox").not(this).attr('checked', true);
    else
        $("#selectallcontainer :checkbox").not(this).attr('checked', false);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure javascript solution:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9FGt/).

Simply attach the function to the onClick event of your 'Select All' checkbox and wrap the rest of your options in a div like so:

```
<script>
    function checkAll() {
        var checkbox_options = document.getElementById("checkbox_options");
        var checkbox_all = document.getElementById("checkbox_all");

        var checkboxes = checkbox_options.getElementsByTagName("input");        
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = checkbox_all.checked;
        }
    }
</script>

<label><input id="checkbox_all" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll()" />Select All</label><br />
<div id="checkbox_options">
    <label><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox1</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox2</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" />CheckBox3</label><br />
</div>
```